# FilesMatch specify path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
```

How do I specify *only* .html files in base directory?

I want

```
https://www.example.com/page.html
```

But *not* `https://www.example.com/directory/page.html`

Comment: This seems to create an endless loop of pushed files with UAs that do not cache....     

Is there something I can add that will limit 1 set of the pushed files?

Answer (score 2):

Since the rule is in `.htaccess` of the root directory, as became clear from the discussion below, try this

```
<FilesMatch "^\.(html|php)$">
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/[^/]+\.(html|php)$#">
        (your directives)
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#file-and-web, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html.

Comment: Sorry, correcred a typo, copy and try again.

Comment: Try `<LocationMatch>` then:
```
<LocationMatch "^/[^/]+\.html$">
(your directives)
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: `FilesMatch` is not supposed to receive the full path; only the file name proper. Have you already tried `<LocationMatch "^/[^/]+\.html$">`?

Comment: I see. And what is it "where"? `<Directory>`, I suspect? Then yes, neither `<DirectoryMatch>`, nor `<LocationMatch>` is allowed there. You have to move whichever to the server or virtual host config. Not in `.htaccess` either.

Comment: If you have only few subdirectories, perhaps you should create own `.htaccess` in each, to override `.htaccess` in the root directory.

Comment: I had in mind denying files from the directories altogether, but it seems that it is not what you want. I have another idea: use `<If>` within your `<Files>` and check how namy slashes there are in `REQUEST_URI` there (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html). Something like `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/[^/]+\.html#">`.

Comment: You've forgotten to close your `</If>` before `</FilesMatch>`. Also, since you want `.php` as well, `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/[^/]+\.(html|php)#">`.

Comment: Then you might want to accept the answer, which I have edited accordingly.